How to open Word Document with Excel VBA macro on Mac?
I have a problem with a macro that opens a Word document using Excel VBA code. This code works well on Windows, however, it doesn't work on Mac. Could someone help me?
This line of code doesn't work on Mac:
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents("Menu_Template.docx")
Function CreateMenu()
'    OPEN WORD TEMPLATE
    Dim objWord ' As Word.Application
    
    On Error Resume Next:
        Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    
    If objWord Is Nothing Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    
    On Error GoTo NoFile:
        ' opens collection of word documents
        objWord.Documents.Open Filename:=(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\Menu_Template.docx"), ReadOnly:=True
        objWord.Visible = True
        objWord.Activate
    On Error GoTo 0:

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents("Menu_Template.docx")
    
    Call GenerateText(objDoc, objWord)
    
    Exit Function

NoFile:
    MsgBox ("Menu template not found")
    Exit Function
End Function


+ "\Menu_Template.docx"), Re  here I would try using a forward slash instead of backslash.
